# how to find out the length of a list in jquery after filtering the list using a function

Tags: jquery, list, filter

I am filtering a list when a checkox is clicked.I wanna find out if the list is empty, after filtering the list and i want to set a empty text on the list(if there are no li) saying No Data Found.
Filter function on check box click:

```
$('.chk_box').change(function() {
   if ($('input:radio[name=star1]:checked').val()==1) {

     $("#mainpanel").fadeOut(500);
     $("#allapps >li").hide();
     $("#allapps >li[data-rate-filter=1]").show();

   } else if ($('input:radio[name=star1]:checked').val()==2) {
     $("#mainpanel").fadeOut(500);
     $("#allapps >li").hide();
     $("#allapps >li[data-rate-filter=2]").show();
   } 
});
```

i tried `$("#mylistid li").length`, but its not giving the length after filtering.

Comment: can you show your html ?

Comment: <div class="group_container">
    <div class="group_header">
                        <h1>More Recommendations</h1>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
   <div><ul id="allapps"></ul></div>
   </div>
this is my html... i dynamically append the <li> into the <ul>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hide the filtered items, you can count the not-hidden elements this way:

```
$("#mylistid li:visible").length
```

More explanation about the `:visible`-selector can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: hey thanks jordumus it worked.. can u please let me know how can i set a empty text in list (saying no data) when there is no li in the list...thanks again!!!

Comment: @prathic  Sorry, I didn't get your question, can you give more information? you can just edit your question and add what you want. Just write a comment here afterwards so I get a notification about it.